# Facebook sdk login fails in android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-authentication

Several weeks ago I finished my facebook login screen in my app, everything worked fine. Today when I was going to login, my app asked for the permissions, I accepted and then instead of run normally and take me to the main screen, throw me an intent to the browser showing this url and a message of "This web page cant be displayed". The url was "fbconnect://success#access_token='.....'&expire_time='.....'". I not changed anything in the code nor in the facebook app. The strange thing is that in my facebook page the permissions to the app are granted. Is how if the first thing that the facebook sdk does is launch this intent, but I don't know why. After the permissions are granted in the LoginActivity of the facebook sdk, the first thing that this should do is call the onActivityResult of my own LoginActivity and later call the callback that handles the session changes. But this never happens, the LoginActivity of the facebook sdk launchs this intent to the browser and then everything crashes. Of course from the server side of facebook the permissions to my app are actually granted. I didn't post code because was working several weeks ago, also is only a LoginButton widget, the UiHelper and the session change callback there's no much science in that. Anyone knows some related error?